# How to pass custom values in an Angular $routeParams object?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When configuring the Angular `$routeProvider`, I would like to specify my own custom values in the `routeObject` and retrieve them via the `$route` object that Angular injects.  Is there a proper way of doing this?

Ex:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/administration/user/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'client/app/views/users-details.html',
            myCustomObject: { firstParam: "one", secondParam: "two"}
        })
```

I'm not quite sure how to retrieve this in a controller.  I see that I can access `myCustomObject` via:

```
$route.current.$$route.myCustomObject
```

however, I can't help but wonder if `$$route` is considered a private variable and shouldn't be accessed directly.  However, short of using convoluted `$q` promise in a resolve to inject the value, I don't see another way.

Am I missing the obvious somewhere?  Is accessing my object via the `$$route` object an acceptable manner, or could this be problematic in a future Angular build?

Comment: You could use `resolve:` for a similar functionality.

Comment: @runTam Yes - that's what I meant by a convoluted $q promise, but that seems like a lot of extra work for something that I would have expected to be simple.

Comment: The `$q` promise is not required in the `resolve:` function, you could return your object right away.

Comment: @runTam Really?  I tried that but failed to get it working.  Maybe I was trying to make it too complicated.  Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Please see @rob's answer below.

Comment: @runTam I tried again, and am still failing.  Please see my comment below `@rob`'s answer.  Tx

Answer (score 2):

As runTarm mentioned you can use resolve and just return an object from the resolve function instead of a promise. e.g.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/administration/user/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'client/app/views/users-details.html',
        resolve: {
            myCustomObject: function() {
                return { firstParam: "one", secondParam: "two"};
            }
        },
        controller: 'MyCtrl'
    })
```

Controller:

```
var MyCtrl = function(myCustomObject) {
    //you should be able to use myCustomObject here
}
```

Comment: Is `myCustomObject` then injectable into my controller?  Or do I have to retrieve it another way?  I could have sworn I tried that already and failed.  I'll have to try again.

Comment: Ok - I tried this again, and am still failing.  If I try to inject myCustomObject in my controller, I get an error message: unknown Provider 'myCustomObjectProvider'.  How do I access `myCustomObject` from within my controller?  Do I need to access it through the $route object or something else?

Comment: I've just noticed that you havn't specified the controller in `$routeProvider`, the `resolve:` will works only when the controller is specified in `$routeProvider` and won't in `ng-controller`.

Comment: @runTarm I edited my answer to include the controller. Eric, did that fix it for you?